# What kind of sample is this?

Tags: sample

I took a sample from the university, but I  stipulated that the sample students  have to be at a specific mental age: 19 at the first year. The number of all students at the 1 year is known, but the size of the students at the age of 19 at the 1 year is unknown, I took the sample through searching for the students who I wanted by non random, every students I found at 1 year I was asking them about their age, and who were 19y I took them.
my question is: what we call this sample?

Comment: Do you mean mental age of 19, or physical age?

Comment: The second key thing needed to answer your question is what you mean by "I took the sample through searching for the students ... by non random".  If you really do mean that this part of the search was non random, then irrespective of what happens next or how you get down to those who are 19 years old (physical or mental) is not a random sample and hence is best called a convenience sample, as timbp has said.  But do you perhaps mean your first search was random, rather than "non random"?

Comment: I'm very confused. What do you mean by "at the 1 year"? Also, in the first sentence you specify mental age, but later you say you asked students their age - people do not know their "mental age" (indeed, the concept of mental age is now deprecated in psychology). I also wonder just how you searched for students.

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely call this a convenience sample.

Comment: Hi, @timbp, would you mind elaborating on this a little? It's nice to have a bit more information.